# Custom Permissions for a Specific PHP Script

Tags: php, security, permissions

I am developing a website which provides the option that clients can upload their PHP scripts to a specific directory on my server. I want to make sure that my system is secure, and thus I do not want people to be able to use those PHP scripts to edit or view files outside of the directory they are uploaded to. In other words, if there is a file at `public_html/directory1/foo.php`, it should only be able to edit and view files in `public_html/directory1`, and should not be able to edit or view files anywhere else on the system. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *super* dangerous. Technically there are ways to do this if you know your way around linux/windows user and group configuration, `Apache` configuration, and `PHP` configuration. You'll need to run `Apache` under a user with extremely specific permissions and configure PHP to forbid certain types of commands (most notably the `exec`/`system` commands, but there are a lot of other ones that are likely to get you in trouble).

I'd strongly suggest you try to figure out a way to avoid giving your users the right to upload files to a folder where they'll be evaluated by the server as PHP. There's just too many things that can go wrong, and too many settings that can be overlooked.

If you do decide to go this route, do a lot of reading on secure PHP configuration and [Apache Privilege Separation](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PrivilegeSeparation).

Comment: What other route could I go? My site needs to allow developers to write web apps, and those apps need to be hosted on my serrver. A ton of services such a shared hosting sites must face a similar problem. Am I making this way too hard or something?

Comment: Personally, I would set up a separate server that is dedicated to running third-party code. You'll still have to do a lot of locking-down (make sure that system files are not modifiable by the Apache user and that your PHP settings do not allow certain functions to be called), but it would be easier to do in a dedicated environment, and if you miss something, it limits the damage they can do.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is a server side script, I belive you'll find it hard to properly secure your system. Having said that, you can limit those files by running the apache server by a user which have no access to other directories, check [SElinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) for more info. please note that it's really hard to do so, you might forget even one file which can be used later to hack the system.

A better way might be running these server on top of a VM, so that even if someone hijacks the VM, you could always shut it down and restore it's data.

Comment: The thing is, that there could be a ton of files that need similar permissions as the one described. Making an individual VM running for hundreds of individual php scripts seems not managable.  I also found the open_basedir which I could set via ini_set for each individual file... Does that sound like a good idea?